# Warning of Google Play Developer policy violation: Action Required (Android.permission.CAMERA)

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-developers-console, privacy-policy

I received this mail from Google App store:

> Our records show that your app, xxx, with package name xxx.xxxx.xxxx, currently violates our User Data policy regarding Personal and Sensitive Information.
>
> Policy issue: Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. Your app requests sensitive permissions (e.g. camera, microphone, accounts, contacts, or phone) or user data, but does not include a valid privacy policy.
>
> Action required: Include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's Store Listing page and within your app. You can find more information in our help center.
>
> Alternatively, you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user data.
>
> If you have additional apps in your catalog, please make sure they are compliant with our Prominent Disclosure requirements.
>
> Please resolve this issue by March 15, 2017, or administrative action will be taken to limit the visibility of your app, up to and including removal from the Play Store. Thanks for helping us provide a clear and transparent experience for Google Play users.

Code in manifest:

```
<manifest >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I have search the answer in many place but I didn't understand. The step what we have to follow and how I will get the policy link and what I have to write in the app also.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100397/warning-of-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required)

Answer (score 4):

**Camera** is a [sensitive permission](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/personal-sensitive/) that triggers the requirement of a Privacy Policy. Other sensitive permissions: record audio, read phone state, get accounts, read contacts.

Your options are:

- If you **don't need** access to camera, update your manifest file and remove the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` line
- If you **need** access to camera, update your app listing page by adding a Privacy Policy.

How to add the Privacy Policy to your app listing page:

1. Log into your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select All Applications
3. Select the application
4. Click Store Listing
5. Enter the public URL of your Privacy Policy at the Privacy Policy field:

[image: Privacy Policy URL field on Play Store via TermsFeed]

Note that you need to host the Privacy Policy on your website, Google won't host it for you.

Where to host your Privacy Policy:

- Your website
- [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com)
- [Medium blog](https://medium.com)