# Rejected app Issue: Violation of Permissions policy

Tags: android, google-play-services

I recently sumbitted an app for the Play store. The app got rejected and I have no clue as to how to fix it. The error is clear enough, but not the solution.

Issue: Violation of Permissions policy  After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):
Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality {Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler)}. Please remove these permissions from your app.
Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised declaration form.

I find the UI of the Google Play Store to be very confusing for me. They aren't answering any emails and I'm at a loss of what to do.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: What's your application's purpose? Your app should not contain any extra permissions.

Comment: Read the error... it looks like you're saying you're the default phone handler and you have no code that handles that. Maybe? Do you need those permissions? If you don't, remove and re-submit.

{Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler)}

Comment: Read call logs, write call logs, get accounts.. very sensitive permissions.. do you really need that all?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes I do need them. The app is for a service handling phone call information (just call duration actually). Sensitive information that it is, is it not possible to get permission for an app such as this then?

Comment: This is the review:

Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality {Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler)}. Please remove these permissions from your app.
Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised declaration form.

Comment: I've found they sometimes take 2-3 business days to answer support requests.  Every now and then someone will be available for live chat, so you can try to keep an eye on that and maybe get lucky that way.

Comment: Luck in all honor, but I'm sure that there is a system in place for these situations. I have the feeling that I need to declare these permissions somewhere but I don't know where.

Comment: this may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100397/warning-of-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required

Comment: Don't use any SMS or CALL_LOG permission until & unless your app's core functionality depends on them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. See meta

Comment: Google had already started mailing developers almost more than 8 months ago , to review their apps for usage of any sensitive permissions related to SMS & CALL_LOG.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because questions about [app store policies are off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165). You will need to ask the company itself about their policies, as they are subject to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put it out there. I resolved this by removing the permissions and only rely on [PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager)
for my purposes.

Answer (score 5):

**If you're using any SMS or CALL_LOG related permission you need to submit a Permissions Declaration Form for your app.**

This new policy is designed by Google to ensure that apps asking for these permissions have core functionality related to them and need full and ongoing access to the sensitive data in order to accomplish the app's primary use case.

[Android Developers Blog  SMS/Call Log Policy Changes](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html)

[Please refer here to understand the details on policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

Comment: In my case, I selected SMS handler permission by mistake. Now my app got rejected. I dont even used SMS services in my project. Now I want to remove SMS handler permission from sensitive app permission section from google play console. But I can not remove it. Will you know how to remove It ?

Answer (score 1):

you face this error because of some critical permission in manifest file. e.g GET_ACCOUNTS,READ_PROFILE. So for this you have to mention privacy policy page url if you have website or create your own privacy policy using following link:

https://privacypolicygenerator.info/