# Google Play rejected app because of it's uploading users' Contact information

Tags: android, google-play, contacts, policy

App removed from google play store due to the following reason:

> **APK HAS A PROMINENT DISCLOSURE BUT THE DISCLOSURE IS NOT ADEQUATE** Your app is uploading users' **Contact** information to
>   `https://domen.com` without an adequate disclosure.

Because of application is for international call app we are using a lot of permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The application does not upload information about the user's contact ("Address Book").

In a not google mentioned that the Contact data is sent to our host.

Comment: Any solution did you got for this issue @Vahe

Answer (score 3):

I feel your pain; Google Play rejection is often arbitrary and getting to the bottom of it (with an actual human on the other end) is next to impossible. That said, **Google Play support is considered off-topic here**. This question will probably be closed soon enough.

That said, extra permissions are not the reason. What you probably have is a genuine case of an HTTP request with some information that originates in the contact list. As far as I can tell, Google's screening robot uses some kind of data path analysis internally. Obfuscating the data path (by using reflection and such) might get you off the hook.

One more data point: my app was once delisted *over an old version in the beta channel*. The beta version from a couple of years ago had a behavior that Google once tolerated but then didn't (a direct link to an APK). Once I've replaced the version in the beta channel, Play was happy again. See if you have something like that. The takedown notice I've got from them didn't make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

The Reason For Rejection after a over 2 months Struggle is cause of Non Compliance of the apps in any of the stages Internal / Closed / Open Testing / Production

[image]

Please make sure once the app is Removed by google ,the roll out the **release** to **100%** & Make sure all the Internal / Closed / Open Testing / Production have the version which is complaint with the Google Policy.
with "Google bots" taking over approval process and if u enter this  Policy Loop and will never be able to reach the Contacts to find help.