# Google Play Console App Rejection APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY AND PROMINENT DISCLOSURE

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My App got Rejected due to below Reason.

Your app is uploading users' Contact List  information without a prominent disclosure. Make sure to also post a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Developer Console and from within the Play distributed app itself.

I have already added `Runtime Permission` for contacts in my app. Including required permission in `Manifest` as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

I have also added `Privacy Policy` in `Google Play Console` with valid URL and content as well.

I am not getting how to tackle this issue and what changes should i apply to my `APK` to approved for go Live.

I also checked with other answers but it doesn't seem to be helping to overcome this issue.

Any help or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159257/google-play-rejected-app-because-of-its-uploading-users-contact-information

Comment: How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @Jay Rathod RJ how did you solve this problem, I have the same for the contact list.

Comment: May [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149753/2289835) help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a privacy policy to your Google Play listing.

In the Play Console Go to App Content > Privacy Policy (Click "Manage"). There you can insert your privacy policy URL.

In your privacy policy you will need to disclose what information you are collecting from your users and why.

Make sure you have added a screen in your app that links to the privacy policy and has an "accept privacy policy" button.

Comment: Yes , it is already added their in play console inside app content...

Comment: Have you added a consent screen in your app?

Comment: Consent screen you mean Privacy Policy link up on app side ?

Comment: Yes, you create a screen in your app e.g. saying "Do you allow for collection of data inside your app in accordance with our privacy policy?". You add the privacy policy link to it. Then add a "Accept" button to it. Then after they clicked the button you can start to collect the data.

Comment: I am linking up that already while user do Sign Up .. their is check box and hyper link for privacy policy ..

Comment: @user14678216 User concent screen means can we put a dialog their call User Data Collection Disclosure and provide or write collected data informations and it's usages ?

Answer (score 2):

Your app needs valid Privacy policy - which should explicitly mention - Why you collect Contact list from user, How the data(contact list) will be used by your app.

Prominent disclosure - You need to present Dialog/Screen to end user who can understand better, Why & How Permission should be accepted by user and take consent before displaying Default Android permission dialog.
Video to explain Prominent disclosure [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=57&v=b0I1Xq_iSK4&feature=youtu.be)