# Play Store App Removed due to: Your app is uploading users' Image information without a prominent disclosure

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play

Our app removed from Play Store

APK REQUIRES PROMINENT DISCLOSURE​

Your app is not compliant with the **user data** and **mobile unwanted** Software policies. Your app is uploading user's image information without a prominent disclosure.

But we don't collect user images. We developed the app on Expo (react-native). We use `expo-file-system` package and `expo-document-picker`. In those packages we only let user to download **mp3** and **mp4** and they can only select **audio** or **video**. We appealed but still they are sending same email.

Here is my dependency array:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.3.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "5.17.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "expo": "^50.0.3",
    "expo-application": "~5.8.3",
    "expo-av": "~13.10.4",
    "expo-blur": "~12.9.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.11.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.7.0",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-device": "~5.9.3",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.10.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~16.0.5",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.1",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-localization": "~14.8.3",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.5",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.10.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-store-review": "~6.8.3",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~3.3.0",
    "i18n-js": "^4.3.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.2",
    "react-native-appsflyer": "^6.12.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^12.1.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-purchases": "^7.5.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.0",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "13.6.4",
    "recyclerlistview": "^4.2.0"
}
```

Do anyone knows to fix it?

I tried to appeal. I tried to upload new version but none of them seems to working.

Comment: We can't answer this sort of customer service questions. We don't know what your app does. If Google have made a mistake you need to talk to them.

Comment: you just need to declare that your app can access photos, basically anything your app can do, even though you not collecting on the backend, but your app has the access the photos, declare any input data the app can have from user, photos, location, document.

Answer (score 1):

- The issue here is that Google Play's policies require a prominent disclosure for certain types of data collection. In your case, you mentioned that you are using the expo-document-picker package to allow users to select audio or video files. This package uses the Android Intent mechanism to open the file picker.
- The issue here is that the Android Intent mechanism does not provide a prominent disclosure for the data being collected. Google Play requires a prominent disclosure for any data collection, including the data collected by the expo-document-picker package.
- According to Google, a prominent disclosure should be displayed in cases where users may not expect their personal and sensitive user data to be required for policy-compliant features or functionality within an app. The disclosure must be within the app itself, not just in the app description or on a website. It must also be displayed in the normal usage of the app and not require the user to navigate into a menu or settings. The disclosure must describe the data being accessed or collected.
- APK HAS A PRIVACY POLICY​ BUT IT IS NOT ADEQUATE : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/206178417/apk-has-a-privacy-policy%E2%80%8B-but-it-is-not-adequate?hl=en
- HELP! "APK REMOVED FROM PLAYSTORE BECAUSE OF POLICY AND PROMINENT DISCLOSURE" : https://groups.google.com/g/androidscript/c/6UqsLOS19lg?pli=1
- Google Play Console App Rejection APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY AND PROMINENT DISCLOSURE : [Google Play Console App Rejection APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY AND PROMINENT DISCLOSURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929059/google-play-console-app-rejection-apk-requires-valid-privacy-policy-and-prominen)